# Was trying to make a text animation and got this error

Tags: html, css

using this in vs code:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
    background: url(/resources/back.png);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
```

show this error:

```
Also define the standard property 'background-clip' for compatibilitycss(vendorPrefix)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to get started with this community. Typically there should be some kind of question in your post.

Comment: Have you tried to define the property `background-clip`?

Comment: read.the.error. Quite clear me thinks.

Comment: Provide some additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers require the -webkit- prefix and some don't.

Most notably, Firefox doesn't.

A useful source of such info is [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-clip)

So, in your code set both, with the unprefixed version after the prefixed one so a browser will pick up the more standard one if it is able to:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
    background: url(/resources/back.png);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
```

I guess that one day text-stroke won't want the prefix either, but just at the moment, and unusually, Firefox requires the webkit prefix too.